# Generate a specific dictionary structure from list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Hello i have list L given below

`L=[(), (0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]`

And i want to generate a specific dict type as given below from the list.  I want to create a lattice of graph by passing the values of `dict3` as input to graph in networkx python, and so need to create a dict where each tuple's value is all elements with length 1 greater than the length of the tuple.

```
dict3={(): [(0,), (1,), (2,)], (0,): [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)],
       (1,): [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)],(2,): [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)],(0, 1): [(0, 1, 2)], 
       (0, 2): [(0, 1, 2)],(1, 2): [(0, 1, 2)]}
```

Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: For the real slow folks like me, mind explicitly describing what the pattern is here, and why you're struggling to implement it?

Comment: What is going on here?

Comment: Hi @Mitch Actually i want to create a lattice of graph by passing the values of dict3 as input to graph in networkx python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
D = {}
for x in L:
    D[x] = []
    for i in L:     
        if len(x) == len(i) -1:    
            D[x].append(i)
```